# Accounts.onLogin how to get user Id?

Tags: meteor

How do you get the _id of the user that logged in. I have tried the following combinations and I get errors, or undefined

Upon user creation, the user is automatically signed into the application. Is the `user` that is  `returned` by the `Accounts.onCreateUser` function occurring after the user is logged in?

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){

 var user = this.userId / Meteor.user() / Meteor.user()._id 
 console.log(user)

})
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Accounts.onLogin(function(){})`, come with 1 parameter user.

> When it is known which user was attempting to login, the Meteor user
>   object. This will always be present for successful logins.

from the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt).

So this should work.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
  console.log(user.user._id)
});
```

And you should see, all the user document into the server console,check this [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/XiX9zxzHdCYSzEFfC/Leaderboard) for an example.

NOTE: this feature is only available on server side check this [Hooks Accounts.onLogin/onLoginFailure should be available on client](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3572)

Comment: Yes Ethaan, I get the whole user document. However, if I console.log(user._id) I get undefined. The onLogin function is on the server, not the client.

Comment: @meteorBuzz i see that, its weird because you get the whole document, but when you try to access them you get undefined, so let me check it

Comment: @meteorBuzz `console.log(user.user._id)` this is the winner

Comment: why don't use a [hook](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) for this? or use the `onCreateUser`. to fill that when the user its created

Comment: well, the function needs to be performed for new users and those that login. Yes, the 'user' is an object inside user....Thanks for pointing this out. A WInner indeed!!

Comment: Where do i need to include this?

Answer (score 4):

You can always get the _id of the logged-in user via [`Meteor.userId()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_userid). This also works inside the `Accounts.onLogin` callback

```
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
  console.log(Meteor.userId());
})
```

Comment: This threw an error for me when I tried it: ```Exception in onLogin callback: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions. at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:19:1)```

Comment: This does not work. You cannot use Meteor.userId(). @Ethaan answer is correct.

Comment: Why are people saying this doesn't work? It does seem to be working (unless there was a recent Meteor update to make it work)